# Why does this jquery selector work in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-selectors

I have this html:

```
<div id="PaymentTypeOptions">
  <input type="radio" id="payment_Cash" name="PaymentTypeOption" value="1">Cash
  <input type="radio" id="payment_Card" name="PaymentTypeOption" value="2">Card
  <input type="radio" id="payment_Cheque" name="PaymentTypeOption" value="3">Cheque
  <input type="radio" id="payment_Voucher" name="PaymentTypeOption" value="4">Voucher
</div>
```

And am trying to select all of the input types in order to bind them to an event using jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('input:radio[name=PaymentTypeOption]').on('click', function () {
    ShowPaymentType(this);
  });
});
```

The selector works in Chrome but not in Firefox.
I'd appreciate some help as to why this is.

Answer (score 1):

Try after removing quotes from `$('document')`:

change this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: That has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Firefox holds on to some javascript values.
To be honest I'm not sure that this is what is happening, but closing the browser and opening a new one causes the problem to go away.